# Norm of a nilpotent matrix

Tags: matrices, operator-theory, normed-spaces, jordan-normal-form, nilpotence

A proof I was reading used the claim that $\vert\vert{N}\vert\vert_2$ = 1 for a nilpotent matrix $N$. I tried to prove it, and have a couple of questions on it.

First, my "proof": We know that there exists a basis wrt which the matrix of $N$ has $1$'s on the super-diagonal and $0$'s everywhere else.
With this representation, for $x = (x_1, x_2, \cdots, x_n)^T$,  $Nx = (0,x_2,x_3, \cdots, x_n)^T$

From the definition of operator norm, $||N||_p = sup||Nx||_p $ taken over $ ||x||_p=1$. Thus $||Nx||_p = 1 - |x_1|^p \leq 1$

Hence,  $||N||_p \leq 1$. By choosing $x = (0, x_2, \cdots, x_n)^T$ we see that $||N||_p =1 $.

**EDIT 1:** An explicit choice $x = (0, 1,0, \cdots, 0)^T$ also works.

My questions are

1. Is my proof correct?
2. The norm seems to depend on the particular matrix representation used. Isn't this a problem? Can I say in general that "the operator norm of a nilpotent matrix is unity"?

**EDIT 2**: I read the book again and I  see I misunderstood. The remark comes in the context that a Jordan block $J_i = \lambda_iI + N_i$, where $N_i$ is nilpotent and $||N_i||_2 = 1$. Of course, $N_i$ has the exact structure I used above in my proof, and it is never suggested that all nilpotent matrices have unit norm.

Comment: If $N$ is nilpotent, so is $c\cdot N$ for all $c$. But $\lVert c\cdot N\rVert_2 = \lvert c\rvert\cdot \lVert N\rVert_2$.

Comment: I do not follow how that helps.

Comment: Aside from @DanielF's comment, no it's not correct. You need to give a *specific* $x$ with norm $1$ for which you get $1$. And you need to show it cannot be any larger than $1$.

Comment: I thought  $x=(0,x_2,\cdots, x_n)$, with $\Sigma |x_i|^p = 1$ is specific.

Comment: Well, it's not specific, but if we agree that we can find such a vector, we're ok. But you have only shown $\|N\|_p\ge 1$. The big problem is that you're using coordinates with respect to some unknown basis, and $\|\cdot\|_p$ is defined with respect to the *standard basis*.